# How to come back to previous scene and reload data?

Tags: swift, core-data, storyboard

I have two Scenes on Storyboard : One to show a list of items with plus button on the Bar to go to another Scene that has form to add a new item. I'm saving on Local Storage, in the saving function I want to come back to the previous page with the new data.

This is the saving function:

```
   @IBAction func AddTrack(_ sender: Any) {

        let item = TrackItem(context: PersistenceService.context)
        item.kms = Int32(kmsField!.text!)!
        item.liters = Float(litersField!.text!)!
        item.date = textFieldPicker!.text!
        PersistenceService.saveContext()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.TrackList.append(item)
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
    }
```

Knowing that I'm using this function in viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear()

```
func GetData(){
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<TrackItem> = NSFetchRequest<TrackItem>(entityName: "TrackItem")
    do{
      let TrackList = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        self.TrackList = TrackList
        self.tableView?.reloadData()
    }catch{

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NotificationCenter or Delegation (Depends on what you are trying to achieve)

Example NotificationCenter:

VC1, takes a photo:

```
buttonTapped / function () {

        // Upload a Photo()

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } 
        }
```

VC2, shows all photos:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
}


@objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification) {
    //get data, reload data, etc
}
```